# SQL where condition is only receiving one word from the value of the field

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, where-clause

I need to pass to a `where` condition a string instead of the id of the row, because of reasons. The problem is that the condition are somehow only catching the first word of the selected value. For example, look at this piece of code:

```
<select id="brand" name="brand" required>
    <option value="Lorem Ipsum Dolor" selected>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</option>
</select>
```

Then, by echoing the `last_query()`, the condition will show:

```
... WHERE `table.column` = `Lorem` ...
```

Instead of the whole `value`.

This is my query:

```
public function find_id_ano_modelo($marca, $modelo, $ano, $comb)
{
    $this->db
        ->select('ano_modelo.id')
        ->join('modelo', 'modelo.id = ano_modelo.id_modelo')
        ->join('marca', 'marca.id_marca = modelo.id_marca')
        ->where('marca.id_marca', $marca)
        ->where('modelo.modelo', $modelo)
        ->where('ano_modelo.ano', $ano)
        ->where('ano_modelo.combustivel', $comb)
        ->where('marca.tipo = 1');

    $query = $this->db->get($this->table);

    echo $this->db->last_query();

    if ($query) {
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $q) {
            return $q['id'];
        }
    }
}
```

That is being called in my `edit` method from my controller:

```
...
$marca = $this->input->post('id_marca');
$modelo = $this->input->post('id_modelo');
$ano = $this->input->post('ano');
$comb = $this->input->post('combustivel');

$data['id_ano_modelo'] = $this->Modelos_model->find_id_ano_modelo($marca, $modelo, $ano, $comb);
....
```

Comment: How are you building the query? Where/how are you getting the values you use to build it?

Comment: @AlexTartan The query is built the way the documentation explains, and the values are being retrieved as POST from the form. Look my edit, please.

Comment: Can you `echo $marca;` (or the corresponding value for that `<select>`) ?

Comment: @AlexTartan Yes. It also echoes only the first word.

Comment: try a little hack: replace spaces with '_' in the view and replace them back in the controller

Comment: @AlexTartan Nothing. It still brings only the first word. Agh...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101610/discussion-between-mfgabriel92-and-alex-tartan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing it in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101610/discussion-between-mfgabriel92-and-alex-tartan), the error was solved:

The request was being sent via an ajax call and the dropdown was built with:

```
modelo.append('<option value=' + v.modelo + '>' + v.modelo + '</option>');
```

The problem was the missing double-quotes around the value. Without them, each word of the value was transformed into an html property:

For this string:

```
QQ 1.0 ACT 12V 69cv 5p
```

This was generated:

```
<option value="QQ" 1.0="" act="" fl="" 12v="" 69cv="" 5p="">QQ 1.0 ACT FL 12V 69cv 5p</option>
```

Adding qoutes here solved it:

```
modelo.append('<option value="' + v.modelo + '">' + v.modelo + '</option>');
```